# How can I insert multiple records in mysql using php at once with one query dynamicaly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an invoice module. There I have fields for items purchased. I am using ajax/jQuery to add new rows when user want to add. Now my question is that how can I add all records in database using PHP, I know how to enter one record but don't know how to add multiple records when we don't know how much records we want to insert. Here is the code,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#JTable").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form name="items" method="post">
<table id="JTable" style="margin-left:50px;">
    <thead>
        <th class="tblfldname">Product</th>
        <th class="tblfldname">Quantity</th>
        <th class="tblfldname">Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <select name="pname[]" class="pname" style="padding:4px; width:150px;">

                    <option></option>

              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="qty[]" style="width:150px; padding:4px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" style="width:150px; padding:4px;" />

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</table>
</form>
            <a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a>


</body>
</html>
```

P.S. All new generated rows's fields have same name.

Comment: This is only HTML and JavaScript. Where is your code that writes to the database?

Comment: mhh the title is about writing to the database, the question is more about reading?! Could you please explain what you want to do in a little more detail?

Comment: Hey I want a php script that can perform actiom of inserting records to mysql on this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through `pname` and do one query for each element:

```
$pname = $_POST['pname'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pname); $i++) {
  $name = mysqli_escape_string ($conn, $pname[$i]);
  $quantity = intval($qty[$i]);
  $prc = doubleval($price[$i]);
  $sql = "insert into bla(name, qty, price) values('{$name}', {$quantity}, {$prc})";
  $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Of course, you have to check if the values make sense... and remember, `[]` are not XHTML-compliant, it's a PHP thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`field0`, `field1`, `field2`)
VALUES
('value0forfield0', 'value0forfield1', 'value0forfield2'), 
('value1forfield0', 'value1forfield1', 'value1forfield2'), 
('value2forfield0', 'value2forfield1', 'value2forfield2'), 
('value3forfield0', 'value3forfield1', 'value3forfield2');
```

---

When you don't know how many records there will be you can do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`field0`, `field1`, `field2`) ";
$query .= "VALUES ";
foreach($record as $row)
{
    $query .= "('".$row['field0']."', '".$row['field1']."', '".$row['field2']."'),";
}
$query = preg_replace("/\,$/", ";", $query);
```

Comment: please read my given description I said "we don't know how much records user want to insert."

Answer (score 0):

By naming your input fields the way you have, there can be data validation problems if one of those fields are left unanswered. IMO it would be better to name your fields something like:

```
<select name="dataset[0]['pname']>...</select>
<input type="text" name="dataset[0]['qty'] ..... >
<input type="text" name="dataset[0]['price'] ..... >

<select name="dataset[1]['pname']>...</select>
<input type="text" name="dataset[1]['qty'] ..... >
<input type="text" name="dataset[1]['price'] ..... >
```

and so forth, then on your posted to page, iterate through your $_POST like:

```
foreach($_POST["dataset"] as $rcd){
   $name = $rcd["pname"];
   $qty = $rcd["qty"];
   $price = $rcd["price";
   ..... do whatever db stuff needs to be done ....
}
```